# Using reduce to pick only certain types of data, like for example numbers only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

I want sparx to be skipped because it's price is Not Available.

This is printing 245NA9530 but I want it 370.

```js
let shoes = [
    { id:205, name:'reebok', price:50 },
    { id:206, name:'adidas', price:45 },
    { id:207, name:'nike', price:150 },
    { id:207, name:'sparx', price:'NA' },
    { id:208, name:'clarks', price:95 },
    { id:209, name:'bata', price:30 },
];
console.log(shoes.reduce((n, {price}) => n + price, 0));
```

Comment: also possible filter+reduce?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=reduce+only+numbers+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Many, many ways. `n + (price==="NA" ? 0 : price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip NA you can add a condition:

```
console.log(shoes.reduce((n, {price}) => typeof price === 'number' ? n + price : n, 0));
```